# Extra space at the bottom of Flow

Tags: qt, qml

I have a QML code like this:

MyItem.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    id: root
    width: parent.width
    height: grid.height

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: root
        color: "blue"
        z: -1
    }

    Flow {
        id: grid
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 5
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Button 1")
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Button 2")
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Button 3")
        }
    }
}
```

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {

        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "hello"
        }

        MyItem {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

If the Flow is wide enough for all three buttons to be at the same line (as with RowLayout) there is an extra empty space at the bottom of the Flow (approximately Button.height * 2). Looks like the Flow height is always calculated as the sum of all its element heights.

What is the logic behind this behavior? How to make the Flow fit its content height?

**EDIT1:** It is not Flow, but 'root' item has the wrong height.

**EDIT2:** [Download the sample app](https://slogpost.ru/temp/FlowApp2.zip)

[image: app]

Comment: I do not check what you point out, you could explain why there is an empty space

Comment: I have added a blue rectangle to observe the space occupied by Flow and I see that it is always the minimum: `Rectangle{
        anchors.fill: grid;
        color: "blue";
        z: -1
    }`  https://i.imgur.com/3E6O3g9.png

Comment: From what I understand is that you want the root element to take the minimum height of the FlowLayout even when the width changes, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc I corrected the code. see https://slogpost.ru/temp/buttons.PNG

Comment: @eyllanesc yes, the root element has wrong height.

Comment: Besides what are you using to show the qml: a QQuickView, QQmlApplicationEngine or what?

Comment: @eyllanesc in my main.cpp: QGuiApplication app(argc, argv); QQmlApplicationEngine engine; engine.load(…) ….  return app.exec();

Comment: I find it strange because QQmlApplicationEngine only supports Window or ApplicationWindow as root element. You can provide an MCVE

Comment: some feedback??

Comment: @eyllanesc see https://slogpost.ru/temp/FlowApp.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the root element the expressions:

```
anchors.fill: parent 
height: grid.height
```

are competing, in the first expression you indicate that the dimensions of the root will take the size of the window and this implies the height but in the next expression you are indicating that the height will no longer be from the window but from the grid, so that generates an indefinite behavior. The only solution is to establish that the width of the root item is that of the window.

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item {
        id: root
        height: grid.height
        width: parent.width
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: root
            color: "blue"
        }
        Flow {
            id: grid
            width: parent.width
            spacing: 5
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Button 1")
            }
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Button 2")
            }
            Button {
                text: qsTr("Button 3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

It seems that you do not know how they work (read https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#details), by default the height that is taken is the implicitHeight.

Also if you use layout you should not set anchors in the items that are directly affected by the layouts, in your case the CommandsTab is affected by the Layout so you should not use `width: parent.width`, is unnecesary.

**CommandsTab.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    id: root
    implicitHeight: grid.height
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: root
        color: "blue"
        z: -1
    }
    Flow {
        id: grid
        width: parent.width
        spacing: 5
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Button 1")
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Button 2")
        }
        Button {
            text: qsTr("Button 3")
        }
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Button {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            text: "hello"
        }
        CommandsTab {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: see EDIT2. the first sample app was not quite correct.

Comment: implicitHeight !

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky I recommend you always ask your background problem, for example in this case the background problem involved a Layout that is not in your initial question. :-)